# Not able to fetch the json data using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Here is the plunker link. I am trying to fetch the json data using Angularjs where data is like object of objects of array.

Plunker link with example

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/4j2wkUD2QpnZcHQQM134?p=preview

Comment: Please suggest how to show the data in table structure in the view part. not able to fetch the data specific like "version property."

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate it over key and value in ng-repeat. check [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LDsLEopig9HPg7L982Qq?p=preview)

like

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in questions">
    {{key}}
    <div ng-repeat="item in value">
      version : {{item.version}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your div tag is not closed properly....

```
 <div ng-repeat="ques in questions">
    <p>{{ques[0].version}}</p>
  </div>
```

your ng-repeat div tag was closed before your

tag.

[Fixed Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/SXLgIVsxIBaYMW4Iy7Cs?p=preview)

[Plunker: for each sub version](http://%20plnkr.co/edit/GFs4tNPgUU5okXcK5wYI?p=preview)

Comment: A more proper iteration to iterate all components would be like.
http://plnkr.co/edit/GFs4tNPgUU5okXcK5wYI?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Some code modifications as `components` properties are dynamic. hence, iterate it dynamic **:**

```
$scope.components = response.data.components;

  $scope.questions = [];
  for(var i in Object.keys($scope.components)) {
    for(var j in $scope.components[Object.keys($scope.components)[i]]) {
      $scope.questions.push($scope.components[Object.keys($scope.components)[i]][j]); 
    }
  }
   console.log($scope.questions);
});
```

**updated Plnkr :** https://plnkr.co/edit/PuvO6PrifWa5WtpeQrvY?p=preview

Comment: Can i create it component wise...like there is a row inside that on the second column there is two row with data...

Comment: @Rohit Mark it as a correct so that it will be helpful for other users as well. Yes you can do it by using `colspan` and `rowspan`.